# How to rollup commit messages in a merge?

Tags: git

I look for message behaviour like squash does - the default commit message containing all the messages of merged branch, so it easy to write the final result based on that. But when committed, the link between the originating branch is lost.

If the branch gets deleted, it's a lost head and gets gc'd eventually.

OTOH, when I do a git merge (no-ff), I get the desired result branch-wise (history keeps references to the merged branches), but the default commit message is not useful ("merge from branch xxx").

So, how do I make it simple, and right?

Answer (score 0):

this works:

> **git merge**
>
> ...
>
> **--log[=]**
>   In addition to branch names, populate the log message with one-line descriptions from at most  actual commits that are being merged.

...

> If --log is specified, a shortlog of the commits being merged will be
>   appended to the specified -m message.

...

> **merge.log**
>
> In addition to branch names, populate the log message with at most the specified number of one-line descriptions from the actual commits that are being merged. Defaults to false, and true is a synonym for 20.

(why is the default off?)